# Trying to run multiple await methods in node JS sequentially, they are running in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, async-await, sharp

I'm trying to combine layers of images into one image. It works fine when I have just one method to fetch the image then another and layers them together, The problem is I need to tint the image before I draw it and they have to be drawn in a certain order. When I introduced the Sharp library to tint images into a buffer and then load the buffer and draw things start to draw out of order

here is the code

```
const drawLayer = async (_layer, _edition) => {
  let element = _layer.elements[Math.floor(Math.random() * _layer.elements.length)];
  addAttributes(element, _layer);

  var path = `${_layer.location}${element.fileName}`;

  console.log("start " + path);
  const buffer = await sharp(`${_layer.location}${element.fileName}`).png().toBuffer();
  console.log("sharp done " + path);
  const image = await loadImage(buffer);
  console.log("load image done " + path);

  ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    _layer.position.x,
    _layer.position.y,
    _layer.size.width,
    _layer.size.height
  );
  console.log("saving edition " + _edition);
  saveLayer(canvas, _edition);
  console.log("\n\n");
};

function draw() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= edition; i++) {
    layers.forEach((layer) => {
      drawLayer(layer, i);
    });
    addMetadata(i);
    console.log("Creating edition " + i);
  }
}
```

If there is only one await call for example I just load the image this way

```
const image = await loadImage(path);
```

there is no problem

a second solution I can figure out is just use the sharp to load the image in a buffer but some how i need to turn that buffer back into either an image or canvas for this method

```
ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    _layer.position.x,
    _layer.position.y,
    _layer.size.width,
    _layer.size.height
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that `drawLayer` is a async function, which means you need to await the function before drawing the next layer. Howwever, according to my knowledge, `Array.forEach` does not support async functions, so you have to do this instead.

```
async function draw() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= edition; i++) {
        for (let layer of layers) {
             await drawLayer(layer, i);
        });
        addMetadata(i);
        console.log("Creating edition " + i);
    }
}
```

I think this might do the trick.

Comment: I think thats on the right track now i get ```await drawLayer(layer, i);
      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules```

Comment: Don't forget, since `draw` is also async, it returns a promise, so u have to do a `.then`, and i think that might be your problem.